# Can we please update the help center to avoid scaring away people interested in folklore?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, [the page "What topics can I ask about here?" in our help center](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is worded in a way that turns away people who are interested in questions about folklore. The phrase "Folklore is on-topic" is listed under the header "What qualifies as a "myth"?", which implies that folklore is a form of myth. As I write in my blog, [nothing could be further from the truth](http://taxicrash.github.io/2015/01/04/Defining-Myth-Folklore-Legend/)<sup>1</sup>.

I wish I was just bringing this up to be pedantic, [but having a false definition will/is scare(ing) away people actually interested in studying folklore](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-we-rename-the-site-to-mythology-folklore-studies#comment760_340).

Could we move the phrase "folklore is on-topic" and place it under the heading "What topics can I ask about here?" instead? I think it would solve a lot of these problems.

**Related**: the meta post https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/62, which deals with the tag wiki for the tag [folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore) where folklore is also incorrectly defined. Ideally, both of these issues would get fixed at the same time.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am linking to my blog, not out of arrogance, but because it quotes/cites sources that are behind paywalls, and therefore are inaccessible to many readers.