# Overlaps with other sites (folklore)

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

The site is named Mythology & Folklore.

Folklore, however, is a broad topic, including music, dance, traditions etc.

Are all folklore questions welcomed, or they should be, when possible, asked on other sites, like Music, Literature or History, a soon as they are on-topic there?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read [this thread](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308/should-we-rename-the-site-to-mythology-folklore-studies?rq=1). In particular, the downvoted one. Shame they all left because the site's relationship to folklore was never clarified before the change happened.

I think if we include folklore, it should be tied to the stories of folklore, in essence folktales. Hopscotch and children's games and folk music and dances all are too different from mythology to be recognizably on topic, in my opinion.

Comment: If they are too different, then why the site is called Mythology and Folklore? It's like The great outdoors would call themselves The Outdoors & Fitness and then refuse questions about training in gym...

Comment: @DanubianSailor Well, it's exactly why I advocated *not* changing the name. Someone who has since left was an advocate for it and apparently a handful of votes determined the outcome.

Comment: If you want to see that reversed, upvote the post saying not to change the name.

Comment: But since the name was changed, it is logical to assume that the topic has extended to match the new name?

Comment: Realistically we are unlikely to be able to change the name again, SE staff made it sound pretty final last time

Comment: @DanubianSailor See above.

Comment: "_Hopscotch and children's games and folk music and dances all are too different from mythology to be recognizably on topic, in my opinion._" You might as well say that stories about Zeus or Odin are too different from hopscotch to be on-topic. The site covers both mythology and folklore. If you want to change its scope so that it covers only mythology and folktales, propose that.

Comment: "_Realistically we are unlikely to be able to change the name again, SE staff made it sound pretty final last time._" Right, so the site covers hopscotch, then, because it covers folklore and hopscotch is folklore. If some want a scope change that the company won't introduce, then okay, that's the position. Don't deal with it by closing questions about hopscotch.